# Tietze Extension Theorem - Munkres Section 35, Theorem 35.1

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, normal-extension

I'm reading the proof for Tietze Extension Theorem from Munkres 2nd. Edition, Section 35, it's $\textbf{Theorem 35.1}$. Part $(a)$ is ok but i'm having trouble understanding the second implication, $(b)$.

$f$ is a continuous map $f:A\to (-1,1)$, we can extend it to $g:X\to [-1,1]$. We now want to find a function $h$ such that $h:X\to (-1,1)$.

Then, we have $\phi:X\to[0,1]$ such that $\phi(D)=\{0\},~\phi(A)=\{1\}$ and define
$$h(x)=\phi(x)g(x).$$

$h$ is continuous since it's the product of continuous functions, and here is where I get stuck:

$$h(a)=\phi(a)g(a)=1\Delta g(a)=f(a)$$ if $a\in A$ and $$h(x)=0\Delta g(x)=0$$ if $x\in D$.

What does $\Delta$ mean? I've read almost all sections from 10 to 43, and never seen it. The only thing I know is $\Delta$ is the diagonal of a product space $X\times X$ but it has no sense here.

Edit 1: Maybe it's a product between de functions, that is not necessarily the usual one?

Edit 2: $\textbf{Theorem 36.2}$ explains $\Delta$ is a kind of product.

Comment: I assume you are reading some kind of digital copy of the book, perhaps corrupted or with other possible issues because my second edition PDF nor my physical copy have any such text using `$\Delta$' in Chapter 4, Section 35, Thm 35.1

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone has noted in the comments, $\Delta$ does not appear in the English versions of Munkres. However, in the Spanish version of Munkres 2nd Edition, one does find $\Delta$! Comparing the two texts, I suspect $\Delta$ is used in place of $\cdot$ to denote multiplication.

For example, the corresponding sections in Theorem 35.1 are $h(x) = 0 \cdot g(x) = 0$ in the English version, and $h(x) = 0\Delta g(x) = 0$ in the Spanish version. As additional evidence, the English version of Theorem 36.2 has $h_{i}(x) = \phi_{i}(x) \cdot g_{i}(x)$ as part of a piecewise definition, whereas the Spanish version has $\phi_{i}(x)\Delta g_{i}(x).$

Comment: Yes, this is definitely true. I'm using the spanish version, thank you very much :)